# Where can I find some ServiceStack/Razor documentantion?

Tags: .net, razor, documentation, servicestack

This is a really newbie question, but where can I find some tutorials or documentation regarding Razor, and how it ties in with ServiceStack ? More specifically, I'm trying to figure out the easiest way to create some login and registration pages and tie them into my services, in order to provide additional functionality for admin users.

I've read what it says on http://razor.servicestack.net/ , and I can browse the source code of the "Razor Rockstars" project; but it feels less like I'm learning a new framework, and more like I'm playing "hide and seek" in the dark with someone else's code.

For example, how would I find out about things like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12640653/servicestack-razor-authentication) without randomly stumbling onto them (like I just did) ?

Basically what I'm looking for is some systematic documentation on how the library is put together, which classes provide which functionality, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The goal of the [razor.servicestack.net](http://razor.servicestack.net) isn't to be a complete reference showing how to build every use-case in a given web application. It's only to explain how it works, [where it fits in ServiceStack's architecture](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Architecture-overview), the role of [razor views vs content pages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13206221/85785) the [rules and conventions ServiceStack uses to specify the View and Templates](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/View-and-template-selection) used.

#### Clean separation between Services vs Views

ServiceStack has a clean separation between Service and HTML Rendering which ServiceStack just considers is another Content-Type. Everything you need to do can be done in within this framework.

#### All Source Code is Available

If for any reason you need to know more details, feel free to refer to the source code which is all contained inside the [ServiceStack GitHub project](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack), starting with the [RazorFormat](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Razor/RazorFormat.cs) which is the starting point for ServiceStack's Razor support.

Comment: Thanks, the link to your answer about [Content vs. View pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13206038/servicestack-razor-default-page/13206221#13206221) was quite useful. Assuming I did not hear about it from you, how would I have found it ? I couldn't Google for this information, since until just now I didn't even know it existed...

Comment: Note: this info was already explained on [razor.servicestack.net/#no-ceremony](http://razor.servicestack.net/#no-ceremony). Otherwise by Googling or asking for it, there's a wealth of info about ServiceStack already on StackOverflow and mailing lists. The docs can only be so useful until there's too much info and no-one will bother reading it. For anything else ask on StackOverflow, you get more specific answers for your specific question. I also added it to [ServiceStack's wiki](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki).